# Timing between words in SPI

Tags: spi, pic

I'm trying to use a dsPIC33F to generate a data signal which must not be interrupted between words. It must be a continuous train of 240 bits. I am clocking the SPI using DMA with 16-bit words, but I am getting gaps in between the words. Is there anything I can do about this or am I stuck with it?

Now here's the odd thing! If I do it using a looping routine continuously writing to the SPI register, there are no gaps! So the DMA is creating these gaps somehow. It would be nice if I could reduce the CPU usage with DMA, as high CPU usage prevents other background tasks from executing.

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: @Leon My code is long, but I have pastebin'd it here for DMA: http://pastebin.com/FRzp77EN   and here for non-DMA:  http://pastebin.com/CF1QvaCB

Comment: what is the instruction rate of the PIC, what is the SPI clock rate and how long are the gaps?

Comment: @Mark DsPIC = ~36.85 MHz, SPI = ~5-6 MHz.

Comment: Make sure you don't have bus arbitration blocking your DMA. (I.e. if the CPU is using the same bus that DMA needs to use to get data from RAM to SPI, then the DMA may be forced to wait for the CPU, missing its timing, if the CPU has a higher priority on the bus or has a "burst mode" that allows it several bus cycles in a row before rearbitration.)

Answer (score 3):

I haven't used the dsPIC DMA engine yet, but this sounds surprising to me.  When you say "continuously writing", does that mean in a loop waiting for the SPIxIF flag (or whatever it's called, not looking it up now)?  I expect that's the same flag that is used to signal the DMA engine to transfer the next word.

If you're not waiting for SPIxIF, then you're just jamming data into the SPI buffer and the output bits aren't predictable.  Perhaps there is a inherent gap between words.  What is the SPI clock rate in terms of instruction cycles per clock?

SPI is inherently synchronous, so a small gap shouldn't cause problems.  Unless you're trying to use the SPI peripheral for other than SPI, your requirement doesn't make sense.

Comment: I'm using SPI to generate video data for an OSD. So it must be continuous or there will be very visible gaps between pixels.

Comment: If master mode has this gap between words (possible, but I'm not convinced), then you can try slave mode instead.  You'd have to feed your own clock into the clock pin, but the data would have to come out synchronous to this clock.  With peripheral pin select, you could possibly even drive the SPI clock input pin from a PWM output without any external connections to the pin.

Comment: Nice idea to use slave mode. Keep in mind that the clock rate needs to be slow enough to leave enough time for interrupt latency to reload the register.

Comment: Not if he's using DMA.  The hardware will reload the register automatically as needed.

Comment: When using the PIC's SPI in slave mode, I believe that the SPI clock is asynchronous to the main CPU clock (at least it is in the PICs I've used).  Even if the SPI clock is in fact synchronous with the PIC's clock, the hardware would not assume that, and would add synchronization delays; I'm not sure which synchronization delays are based off the PIC clock and which are based off the SPI clock, though.

Comment: Yes, there will probably be a short synchronization delay but should be insignificant.  Keep in mind that the SPI data shift register is double buffered.  For transmitting, there is SPIxTXB, which is used to reload SPIxSR at the appropriate times.  I'm not sure how much overlap it actually allows, but it could allow for up to 16 bits worth of write-ahead.  At the very least the DMA hardware would have at least 1/2 SPI clock cycle to load the next word into the shift register (SPIxSR).

Answer (score 1):

On the PIC18xx, the SPI port requires a delay between the end of one word and the beginning of the next.  IIRC, when running the SPI port at a rate of one bit per instruction clock, attempting to feed more than one byte per twelve instruction clocks will cause transmit overrun and data loss.  It's nice to know that you don't seem to have that limitation on the dsPIC, but my guess would be that the DMA doesn't trigger until the SPI is empty, which then ends up imposing a one-cycle delay.  I don't know how DMA works on the dsPIC, but on some processors it's possible to use a timer to operate the DMA; perhaps you could try running DMA to the SPI port every 16 cycles; if there's a one-cycle delay between writing to the port and starting the transfer, the second tick from the timer would come a cycle before the SPI port would have triggered the second DMA.  One limitation of this approach is that unless the SPI port is double-buffered, the DMA would have to run at maximum priority.  Otherwise if one transfer occurred late, the next transfer could cause a buffer overrun.

Comment: SPI peripherals are often useful for purposes other than SPI.  On a PSOC, for example, I use an SPI transmitter to generate video.  The code is written to load the transmit register once every sixteen cycles without checking whether it's ready (on that particular processor, a test and branch would take 13 cycles IIRC, so there'd be no time for the code to do the test).

Answer (score 1):

In your scanline interrupt you where you have:

```
// Then write first DMA words. Successive words requested by SPI module.
// TODO: offset DMA by one word, or we will get duplicates. OR, just write
// a null word first... Whichever is easiest/best.
SPI2BUF = scanline_level_out_dma[0];
SPI1BUF = scanline_mask_out_dma[0];
```

Just set `DMAxCONbits.FORCE = 1` prior to enabling the DMA channel and it will force the first byte as soon as the DMA channel is enabled.

You can also just setup your dummy read channels in continuous mode (rather than single shot) with a 1 word buffer and start them when you boot up and ignore the interrupt, no need to think about them again after that.

In your DMA example you still have SPI interrupts defined:

```
/**
 * _SPI1Interrupt: Primary ISR for SPI1.
 *
 * Only clears interrupt flag at the moment.
 */
void _MY_ISR _SPI1Interrupt()
{
        uint16_t nullread;
        nullread = SPI1BUF;
        nullread = SPI2BUF;
        IFS0bits.SPI1IF = 0;
}
```

I believe this still gets called when DMA is enabled unless you disable the CPU interrupt, that is both the DMA controller and the CPU respond to the interrupt.

This looks like repeating the work of the DMA read channel and on top of that its slow (just use a global rather than a stack variable in an ISR like this).  It may also be blocking your transfer, i don't really know if the DMA controller would reset the interrupt while the CPU was in a handler for that interrupt.

> Now here's the odd thing! If I do it
>   using a looping routine continuously
>   writing to the SPI register, there are
>   no gaps!

This is dangerous without checking SPIxIF, you very well could be garbling what comes out and your test bytes would make that really hard to find.

**EDIT:** With your SPI clock only being about 1/7 of your instruction clock you need to be very careful in the above interrupt handler to clear SPI1IF ASAP or simply disable it all together and let the DMA controller handle it.  To achieve no gap you have less than 7 instruction cycles to get the next word out the SPI unit.  I think you have to completely disable CPU intervention and just let the DMA controller deal with it to have any chance, but even then you have 2 DMA transfers and whatever triggering latency there is from the SPI -> DMA (its 1 instruction clock for SPIxIF to fire for instance).  So its going to be close.

Answer (score 0):

Just set DMAxCONbits.FORCE = 1 prior to enabling the DMA channel and it will force the first byte as soon as the DMA channel is enabled.

These two lines saved my 2 days trouble. I was try an implementation of DMA based SPI in PIC32 MZ. I had enabled the Channel and then Forced a start. At low SPI clocks of less than 1 Mhz all was ok. Once I tried more than 2 mhz (My requirement is 20 Mhz) I started getting First Character alone repeated and rest was ok. Now that changed the order and tried all going fine. Just wanted to express my thanks.